# Help undersanding meromorphics Herglotz functions

Tags: complex-analysis

A meromorphic function $f$ is called  meromorphic herglotz function if $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0$ implies $\mathrm{Im}(f(z))>0$

I need to prove that all the poles and zeros of $f$ are in $\mathbb{R}$. Morover, each pole and zero is simple and the poles and zeros alterante.

There is a [proof](http://books.google.com.mx/books?id=0VH2AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA920&lpg=PA920&dq=herglotz+function+zeros+poles&source=bl&ots=OMMLrqR2Rq&sig=p47uWe5hLy5BtO6_nRv14yU6mfc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MXqbU7-HMtPo8AHooYDoCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=herglotz%20function%20zeros%20poles&f=false) here, but I can't understand why $\operatorname{arg}(f)$ takes all the values in $[0,2\pi)$ and why that implies that all the zeros and poles are in $\mathbb{R}$.

[image: Image here]

Comment: Apparently I have reached my viewing limit for the book. You may want to find another way to post the proof.

Comment: Done, image added.

Comment: You missed half of the definition. $\Im f < 0$ if $\Im z < 0$ also holds.

Comment: nope, that's the definition.

Comment: @reneto : Look at page 920 of the same book. Both must hold.

Answer (score 1):

If a meromorphic function $f$ has a pole or zero at $z_{0}$, then, for a unique non-zero integer $n$,
$$
        f(z) = (z-z_{0})^{n}g(z)
$$
where $g$ is holomorphic near $z_{0}$ with $g(z_{0})\ne 0$. Then
$$
   f(z) = (z-z_{0})^{n}g(z_{0})+(z-z_{0})^{n+1}\left[\frac{g(z)-g(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}\right].
$$
By choosing $z=re^{i\theta}+z_{0}$ with $r$ small enough, you can arrange for the first term to dominate so that the image of $C_{r}=\{ re^{i\theta}+z_{0} : 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi \}$ is very nearly circular.